# Which Java edition do I have?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-me

How can I reliably determine whether my installed Java is J2ME, J2SE or J2EE? Please assume a Linux environment that has one JRE, but no a-priori knowledge of which edition.

A preferential solution would be a one-liner that references some concrete existing resource, ie not compiling code specific to one of these and seeing what fails to build.

Edit: I was hoping the answer would produce one of J2EE, J2SE or J2ME suitable for piping. `java -version` has to be parsed with a-priori knowledge of implementations, e.g. if the output contains JDK, infer J2SE. I am caving and accepting it, but if a new answer that meets this criteria is posted I'll accept that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the bash command`java -version` This should tell you the version of the JDK / JRE you are running, including whether it is J2ME, J2SE or J2EE.

Comment: For example in 'java version "1.6.0_32" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.4) (6b32-1.13.4-1~deb7u1) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)' which part indicates the edition?

Comment: Hm. This works for the Oracle runtime; not so sure about OpenJDK.

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal execute the highlighted command

user@linux:~$ **java -version**

output should be something like :

java version "1.7.0_25"

***Java(TM) SE*** Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

in th bold part it is showing ***Java(TM) SE*** that mean standard edition similarly other will ME,EE and so on

Comment: Please see my comment on Isaac Woods' answer. This seems to work for Oracle runtimes but not necessarily all runtimes.